Azure Data Factory expression to differentiate between null and empty '' string
I have a lookup activity that returns a first row from a dynamic query which is being passed to the ADF pipeline via a parameter.
Most of the queries used are like :
SELECT max(id) as watermark FROM events
If the events table has no rows the lookup activity first row value is null. I can check this in a If activity with the @empty() function like:
@not(empty(activity('lkup_watermark').output.firstrow['watermark']))
However there are also times when the query being passed to the lookup is like:
SELECT '' as watermark
These are for those tables that dont need to load deltas with watermarks
The issue is the @empty function treats both null values and '' values as true
I have also tried using @if() function but still does not differentiate.
Does anyone know the right function in ADF to check if the value is a true null and not a '' value ?
